# How do I animate circles and line with matplotlib?

Tags: animation, matplotlib

I can animate six circles, and I can animate a line. When I try to animate both, I cannot figure out what init() and animate() should return. For six circles I "return tuple(pins)" and for the line I "return line,". Each pin is a "class 'matplotlib.patches.Circle'" and the line is "class 'matplotlib.lines.Line2D'."

When I try to animate both the circles and the line, I have tried many different return statements without success. Here are the some of the results:

return line, tuple(pins) GIVES 'tuple' object has no attribute                       'set_animated'

return tuple(pins) + (line) GIVES can only concatenate tuple (not "Line2D")                              to tuple

return tuple(pins) + tuple(line) GIVES 'Line2D' object is not iterable

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: You say what `pin` is, but not what `pins` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you only need to return something from the animating function if you use blitting.

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html):

> If `blit == True`, func must return an iterable of all artists that were modified or created. This information is used by the blitting algorithm to determine which parts of the figure have to be updated. The return value is unused if `blit == False` and may be omitted in that case.

So just ommiting the `return` altogether may be the easiest option.

If you need/want to use blitting, you need to return an iterable of artists. This can e.g. be a tuple or a list. Unfortunately, it's not clear what `pins` is from the question.

Supposing `pins` is a list,

```
return pins + [line]
```

or if you want to make it a list,

```
return list(pins) + [line]
```

Supposing `pins` is a tuple,

```
return pins + (line,)
```

or if you want to make it a tuple,

```
return tuple(pins) + (line,)
```

Comment: Removing blit from anim worked. Since pins is a list so did adding a line list. Making a tuple, for reasons I no longer remember, was the cause of my problem because I was not handling the tuple correctly. Thank you very much.